# LWR Site layout same header slot on every page

Tags: experience-cloud, lwr, custom-theme-layout

Based on the Build Your Own template I am trying to create a layout with a header slot and a body slot. But I want the header slot to contain the same components the user selected on EVERY PAGE. How can I define a slot global? One of the standard layouts has this option. I don't know how they achieved this. See builder -> theme -> Header and Footer component ->
"Show fixed footer" and "Fix theme header".

```
<template>
        <header data-f6-region class="header">
                <slot name="myheader"></slot>
        </header>
        <main data-f6-region class="body">
            <slot></slot>
        </main>
</template>
```

And

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
/**
 * @slot myheader This is the header slot
 */
export default class TessWebsiteLayout extends LightningElement {
}
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the slot name is supposed to be either header or footer to be globally the same on all pages of the layout. I was testing with several named slots and therefore the names were myheader and myheader2 and therefore not interpreted as global. Would have been cool if it was a parameter instead of a fixed name.